# How can i retrieve data from SharedPreferences and store it in a const?

Tags: flutter, dart, constants, flutter-sharedpreference

I need to get a number from SharedPreferences and store it in a constant. But i couldn't manage to do it.

```
SharedPreferences sp = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
const int index = sp.getInt('index')!;
```

This code throws this error:

```
Const variables must be initialized with a constant value.
Try changing the initializer to be a constant expression.
```

I want to get the data once and never change it again. How can i achieve this?

Comment: You can't const should be constant at compile time, and a value retrieved from shared prefrences is not known at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Put `final` instead of `const` and `await` for it rather than awaiting for the `instance`.

```
SharedPreferences sp = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
final int index = await sp.getInt('index')!;
```

Comment: But i won't be able to use const widgets where i use that number if i make it final instead of const. I need to make widgets const, in order to boost the performance of the app.